# CQL - Uniqueness of elements in a set of user defined types

Tags: cassandra, cql3

C* sets guarantee that all elements in a set are unique. How does it work for user defined types (UDT)?

With simple types, the cell name is just the name of the CQL column concatenated with the column value. For example if we have

```
CREATE TABLE friendsets (
        ... user text PRIMARY KEY,
        ... friends set <text>
        ... );
```

We friends are stored as

```
(column=friends:'doug', value=)
(column=friends:'jon', value=)
```

What if friends is defined as a set of UTD (friends set < frozen Friend >) ? Will the name of the cells 'friends' concatenated with the serialized value of Friend?

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra will serialize the value for frozen types to a BLOB when you save it to a table. The representation on disk should be identical from any other type for your set, but Cassandra will be able to deserialize the bytes to a UDT instance, once read by a query.

Comment: So how is uniqness enforced in a set of UDT? If friend has an id and name, it basically means that I would be able to store multiple friends with the same id...UTD is essentially treated like a tuple - 2 tuples are equal only if all their fields are the same

Comment: Also, how would I update a friend's name? Find the friend by id, delete it, and then insert a new friend?

Comment: Correct, you'd have to remove and re-add the updated friend to your set. For what it's worth, you also have to keep concurrent updates in mind. You should always use individual CQL statements for deleting or adding elements to a set, instead of replacing the whole set in order to avoid overwriting changes from a concurrent update.

Comment: Thanks. Concurrency, and write after read are still a problem with UTDs - if threads  try to update the same UDT object  it is still possible to overwrite changes.

Comment: I guess I need LWT for that